# Manipulate the series and find limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $$ L= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \frac{2^r}{5^{2^r}+1},$$
 then find $L$.

I tried various ways to manipulate it to difference series, but failed to do so.
Please help

Thankyou

Comment: This question (with $x$ instead of $5$) was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586461/find-the-sum-of-the-series-using-differentials).

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks a lot Sir. Can you tell me how to intuitively come up with such an answer.

Comment: You won't like the answer, I'm afraid: exercise, lots of exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\dfrac1{5^{2^r}-1}-\dfrac1{5^{2^r}+1}=\dfrac2{\left(5^{2^r}\right)^2-1^2}=\dfrac2{5^{2^{r+1}}-1}$$

$$\implies\dfrac{2^r}{5^{2^r}-1}-\dfrac{2^{r+1}}{5^{2^{r+1}}-1}=\dfrac{2^r}{5^{2^r}+1}$$

Put $r=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1,n$ to recognize the [Telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) pattern.

Comment: I think that it is $5^{2^r}$ and not $5^{2r}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Thanks! Please find the updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Any tips on how to recognise such telescoping series..??

Comment: @IshanSharma, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591220/frac1-sin-8-circ-frac1-sin-16-circ-frac1-sin-4096-circ

Comment: @IshanSharma, See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422087/solve-tan%CE%B12-tan2%CE%B14-tan4%CE%B18-tan8%CE%B116-tan%CE%B1-cot%CE%B1-for-alpha